# Issue with Mysql group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

After doing some joins and stuff I have table in the following format

```
  name    session_id   status 
    abc         1          null       
    xyz         2          11          
    jack        2          10
    zuck        1          10 
    paul        1          10
```

I want my results to be grouped like this

```
 session_id   name+status                   
    1            abc:-1, zuck:10, paul:10
    2            xyz:11, jack:11
```

So I used MySql group_concat in sql like

```
    SELECT sr.avail_id AS id,sr.student_id, sa1.punctuality_status as associate_punctuality_status, IF(
                    (sa.punctuality_status IS NULL),
                    (group_concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname, ':', '-1'), 
                    (group_concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname, ':', sa.punctuality_status)
                    ),
                    sr.tutor_id AS associate_id, FROM_UNIXTIME( sr.timestart ) AS timestart,  
                    sr.session_id AS session_id, sr.type AS session_type, p.name AS program_name,
             m.name AS module_name, ms.name AS session_name, sr.status as session_status FROM mdl_session_requests AS sr 
        LEFT JOIN mdl_session_attendee AS sa ON ( sr.student_id = sa.user_id AND sr.session_id = sa.session_id )  
        LEFT JOIN mdl_session_attendee AS sa1 ON (sr.tutor_id=sa1.user_id and sr.session_id=sa1.session_id)  
        INNER JOIN mdl_module_session ms ON ms.id = sr.course_id    
        INNER JOIN mdl_module m ON m.id = ms.module_id   
        INNER JOIN mdl_program p ON p.id = m.program_id   
        INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = sr.student_id    
        WHERE sr.tutor_id =438 group by avail_id order by sr.timestart desc
```

error = "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS associate_id, FROM_UNIXTIME( sr.timestart ) AS timestart, sr.session_id AS ' at line 6"

Is something wrong with this sql ?

Comment: *"Some error"*? What error are you getting?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS tutor_id'

Comment: It seems the "from" clause is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     s.session_id AS id,
     group_concat(SEPARATOR ', ' CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname, ':',IF(s1.status IS NULL,'-1',s1.status))), sr.tutor_id

FROM [a table]
GROUP BY session_id
```

Problems:

1. No FORM clause
2. parentesis where not matching
3. `GROUP_CONCAT` can be done on one field, so you need to `CONCAT()` all the values first.

Comment: that was not the actual sql...just an abstraction... I have updated the question

Comment: Use my example to modify your query

Comment: worked like a charm...but I'm still confused what was the problem in previous query ?

Comment: :-) I actually wrote it, under the query.

Comment: "GROUP_CONCAT can be done on one field, so you need to concat all the values first." ..point noted :)